# Magento 2.3.1 suddenly price disappeared from layered navigation

Tags: layered-navigation, elasticsearch, magento2.3.1

I am having this problem and I don't have a clue what is happened. Suddenly in front end price filter from layered navigation don't show in frontend in all categories.

No new module installed. This happened after updated in admin some product prices and reindex.

All catalog is migrated from magento 1. Also in magento 2 I changed price scope to global.

All categories are anchor and price is set to filterable with results for frontend.

Checked database table:

> `catalog_eav_attribute`

and everything seems fine.

[image]

Magento use Elastic search but till now everything was fine.

I don't have any errors in logs for this problem. Also I don't know what other details I shall give here so someone could give me an idea where to look.

> UPDATE

When changed magento search to mysql filter appeared. So I think elastic is the problem.

> Logs from elastic

```
[2019-04-19T10:58:25,815][DEBUG][o.e.a.s.TransportSearchAction] [QfyrxGU] [magento2_product_3_v1][4], node[QfyrxGUgQ4O0j0XV_mBMxw], [P], s[STARTED], a[id=EiVjYWHUR2CNKLZ-KN9iZA]: Failed to execute [SearchReq$
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [QfyrxGU][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [image_label] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Not$
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.TextFieldMapper$TextFieldType.fielddataBuilder(TextFieldMapper.java:779) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.1.jar:6.7.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexFieldDataService.getForField(IndexFieldDataService.java:116) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.1.jar:6.7.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryShardContext.getForField(QueryShardContext.java:166) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.1.jar:6.7.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.support.ValuesSourceConfig.resolve(ValuesSourceConfig.java:95) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.1.jar:6.7.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.support.ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder.resolveConfig(ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder.java:317) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.1.jar:6.7.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.support.ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder.doBuild(ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder.java:310) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.1.jar:6.7.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.support.ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder.doBuild(ValuesSourceAggregationBuilder.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.1.jar:6.7.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AbstractAggregationBuilder.build(AbstractAggregationBuilder.java:139) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.1.jar:6.7.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorFactories$Builder.build(AggregatorFactories.java:335) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.1.jar:6.7.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:811) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.1.jar:6.7.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:620) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.1.jar:6.7.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:595) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.1.jar:6.7.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:386) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.1.jar:6.7.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.access$100(SearchService.java:125) ~[elasticsearch-6.7.1.jar:6.7.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$2.onResponse(SearchService.java:358) [elasticsearch-6.7.1.jar:6.7.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$2.onResponse(SearchService.java:354) [elasticsearch-6.7.1.jar:6.7.1]

[2019-04-18T23:33:53,358][WARN ][o.e.d.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [QfyrxGU] the default number of shards will change from [5] to [1] in 7.0.0; if you wish to continue using the default of [5] shards, you must manage this on the create index request or with an index template
[2019-04-18T23:33:53,412][WARN ][o.e.d.r.a.a.i.RestPutMappingAction] [QfyrxGU] [update_all_types] is deprecated since indices may not have more than one type anymore
[2019-04-18T23:35:53,079][WARN ][o.e.d.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [QfyrxGU] the default number of shards will change from [5] to [1] in 7.0.0; if you wish to continue using the default of [5] shards, you must manage this on the create index request or with an index template
```

Any help please?